# UICollectionView Not Scrolling Vertically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scroll, uicollectionview

I'm new to ios development. Was creating a grid view with UICollectionView. View doesnt scroll vertically, but when i change the scroll direction to horizontal it does. I want it to scroll vertically

[image]

Comment: Add the code which you've used to create `collectionView`.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you create it in code with `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
```

or if you are working with an existent collection view

```
if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
}
```

You have to set vertical scroll from UICollectionView Properties.
[image: UICollectionView Properties]

> `UICollectionView` has the properties `BounceHorizontally` and
>   `BounceVertically`. Setting the vertical to YES `did` the trick.
>
> Set the ScrollView properties PagingEnable --> YES

You have to add

> self.collectionView.pagingEnabled = YES;

Comment: I did this, works fine for horizontal not for vertical                                                                     if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        }

Comment: Edited my answer. Please check

Comment: did as you have shown in the pic, still ain't working

Comment: Please check in properties in that Bounce--> Bounce Vertically check mark enable. Edited my answer plz check that

Comment: Yes it has been set to bounce vertical

Comment: can i have your mail please

Comment: have uploaded below

Comment: still it isn't working. is there anything wrong with my code

Comment: brother i have got a horizontal scroll view above the UICollectionView. Could it be the scrollView jamming with CollectionViews vertical Scroll

Answer (score 0):

```
    import UIKit

    class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{


        //Variables of Grid View

        @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!


        @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!{
            didSet{
                scrollView.delegate = self
            }
        }

        @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!

        var slides:[AdSlides] = [];
        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            setGradientBackground()
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()


            collectionView.dataSource=self
            collectionView.delegate=self


            //AdSlides :start


            slides = createSlides()
            setupSlideScrollView(slides: slides)

            pageControl.numberOfPages = slides.count
            pageControl.currentPage = 0
            view.bringSubviewToFront(pageControl)

            //AdSlides :complete

        }

        //MARK: - Collection View



        // Create an array that contains our data
        var array = ["Air Condition", "Battery", "Engine", "Modify", "Paint","Sticker","Audio","Interior","Tyre","Wash","Tow","Check Up","Banana","Apple","Apricot"]

        var photo = [UIImage(named: "ac"),UIImage(named: "battery"),UIImage(named: "engine"),UIImage(named: "modify"),UIImage(named: "paint"),UIImage(named: "sticker"),UIImage(named: "sound"),UIImage(named: "interior"),UIImage(named: "tire"),UIImage(named: "wash"),UIImage(named: "tow"),UIImage(named: "checkup"),UIImage(named: "Banana"),UIImage(named: "Apple"),UIImage(named: "Apricots")]

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return array.count
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

            if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
                layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
            }
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
            cell.gridLabel.text = array[indexPath.row]
            cell.gridImage.image = photo[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }


        //MARK: - End Of Collection View






        //MARK: - Function For Blue Gradient Background
        func setGradientBackground() {
            let colorTop =  UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 68.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
            let colorBottom = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 206.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor

            let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
            gradientLayer.colors = [colorTop, colorBottom]
            gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
            gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds

            self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at:0)
        }



        // MARK: - ADSLIDE's
        func createSlides() -> [AdSlides] {

            //API IMAGES
            let dataImg = NSData(contentsOf: URL(string: "https://source.unsplash.com/random")!)
            let dataImg2 = NSData(contentsOf: URL(string: "https://source.unsplash.com/random")!)
            let dataImg3 = NSData(contentsOf: URL(string: "https://source.unsplash.com/random")!)

            let slide1:AdSlides = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AdSlides", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! AdSlides
            slide1.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image1")

            let slide2:AdSlides = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AdSlides", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! AdSlides
            slide2.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image2")

            let slide3:AdSlides = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AdSlides", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! AdSlides
            slide3.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image3")


            let slide4:AdSlides = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AdSlides", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! AdSlides
            slide4.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Apple")


            let slide5:AdSlides = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AdSlides", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! AdSlides
            slide5.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Banana")

            let slide6:AdSlides = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AdSlides", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! AdSlides
            slide6.imageView.image = UIImage(data: dataImg3! as Data)

            let slide7:AdSlides = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AdSlides", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! AdSlides
            slide7.imageView.image = UIImage(data: dataImg2! as Data)

            let slide8:AdSlides = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AdSlides", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! AdSlides
            slide8.imageView.image = UIImage(data: dataImg! as Data)


            return [slide1, slide2, slide3, slide4, slide5,slide6,slide7,slide8]
        }

        func setupSlideScrollView(slides : [AdSlides]) {
            scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
            scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width * CGFloat(slides.count), height: view.frame.height)
            scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true

            for i in 0 ..< slides.count {
                slides[i].frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
                scrollView.addSubview(slides[i])
            }
        }

        /*
         * default function called when view is scolled. In order to enable callback
         * when scrollview is scrolled, the below code needs to be called:
         * slideScrollView.delegate = self or
         */
        func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            let pageIndex = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x/view.frame.width)
            pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageIndex)


            /*
             * below code changes the background color of view on paging the scrollview
             */
            //        self.scrollView(scrollView, didScrollToPercentageOffset: percentageHorizontalOffset)


            /*
             * below code scales the imageview on paging the scrollview
             */


            //cancel horizontal scrollView
            if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 || scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 {
                scrollView.contentOffset.y = 0
            }
        }


    }
```